# How to determine the minimum number of bits i need

Tags: math, byte, bit

Determine the minimum number of bits you would need for a memory address if memory could have up to 80 million bytes, with and without a calculator. Assuming byte addressing. Thank you

Comment: Other than using log2?

Comment: Would it be 8192 than? 1024 * 8 ? I am so confused thanks you

Comment: Where did you get 8192?

Comment: @beaker 1024 * 8

Comment: Okay, where did you get 1024 * 8?

Answer (score 2):

Use that 2^10=1024 is approximately 10^3, that is for any 3 decimal digits you need 10 bit. Then estimate how to cover the additional factor 80.